# browser-sync proxy fails to connect

Tags: browser-sync

Have a simple rack based server running on `localhost:9292`

And gulp task to proxy this address..

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: 'localhost:9292',
    port: 4000
  });
});
```

On the CLI we get this..

```
[17:36:34] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[17:36:34] Finished 'browser-sync' after 9.75 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:9292
[BS] Access URLs:
Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.1.218:3000
UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://192.168.1.218:3001
```

And....Nothing. No error message, the browser just spins and nothing happens.

[Based on these BrowserSync instructions](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-proxy), it appears that this is all I need to do.

Gulp version 3.9.1
Node v6.3.1
browser-sync 2.14.0